# Changin top div height but below items not change position

Tags: jquery, css, html

There are some float divs top of each other.when user hovered on on of them,the height increases with jQuery command:

```
 $(".concert").hover(function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".concert[opened='opened'] .concertbody").animate({ height: "0px" }, { duration: 400, queue: false });
        $(this).parent().find(".concert[opened='opened'] .concertHeader .middle").css("background-image", "url(Images/concert-header-back.png)");
        $(this).parent().find(".concert[opened='opened'] .concertbody").css("border", "none");
        $(this).parent().find(".concert[opened='opened'] .concertbody .concertDetails").css("visibility", "hidden");

        $(this).find(".concertbody").animate({ height: "276px" }, { duration: 400, queue: false });
        $(this).find(".concertHeader .middle").css("background-image", "url(Images/concert-header-back-hover.png)");
        $(this).find(".concertbody").css("border", "1px solid whitesmoke");
        $(this).find(".concertbody .concertDetails").css("visibility", "visible");
        $(this).parent().find(".concert[opened='opened']").removeAttr("opened");
        $(this).attr("opened", "opened");
    });
```

The layout is Ok,other divs goes down,but when i use firebug and check the other divs tag,the position doesn't change.

The Html of the page :

```
 <div class="parent">
                <div class="concert" id="ct1">
                    <div class="concertHeader">

                        <div class="middle">
                            <span class="concertName">کنسرت همایون شجریان</span>
                            <span class="concertCity">تهران</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="concertbody">
                        <div class="concertDetails">

                            <span>محل دیدار : سالن همایش های بین المللی میلاد تهران</span>
                            <select class="test2">
                                 <option value="1">16:30</option>
                                <option value="2">18:50</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="test">
                                 <option value="1">بیست و هشتم اردیبهت ماه نود و دو</option>
                                <option value="2">بیست و هشتم اردیبهت ماه نود و دو</option>
                                <option value="3">بیست و هشتم اردیبهت ماه نودو دو</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="concert" id="ct2">
                    <div class="concertHeader">

                        <div class="middle">
                            <span class="concertName">کنسرت همایون شجریان</span>
                            <span class="concertCity">تهران</span>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="concertbody">
                        <div class="concertDetails"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="concert" id="ct3">
                    <div class="concertHeader">

                        <div class="middle">
                            <span class="concertName">کنسرت همایون شجریان</span>
                            <span class="concertCity">تهران</span>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="concertbody">
                        <div class="concertDetails"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="concert" id="ct4">
                    <div class="concertHeader">
                        <div class="middle">
                            <span class="concertName">کنسرت همایون شجریان</span>
                            <span class="concertCity">تهران</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="concertbody">
                        <div class="concertDetails"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="concert" id="ct5">
                    <div class="concertHeader">
                        <div class="middle">
                            <span class="concertName">کنسرت همایون شجریان</span>
                            <span class="concertCity">تهران</span>
                        </div>

</div>
```

And The CSS :

```
.container {
    width: 972px;
    height: 532px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.parent {
    width: 324px;
    height: 490px;
    float: right;
}

    .parent .concert {
        width: 324px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 2px;
    }

.middle {
    --background-image:url("../Images/concert-header-back.png");
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2JmYmZiZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlNWU1ZTUiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(191,191,191,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(191,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    width: 320px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.concertHeader:hover .middle {
    width: 320px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}

.rightSide {
    background-image: url("../Images/concert-header-right-side.png");
    width: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}

.leftSide {
    background-image: url("../Images/concert-header-left-side.png");
    width: 5px;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
}

.concertName, .concertCity {
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: Black;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.concertName {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.concertCity {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.concertbody {
    height: 0px;
    width: 318px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

What should i do for this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.parent .concert {
        width: 324px;
        margin: 2px;
    }`

http://jsfiddle.net/yxMSz/

You have a fixed height on .parent .concert

You can add a min-height instead if you need to.

Comment: Yes,That Worked!Thank you so much!and why i shouldn't set height?

Comment: If you set a height the box can't get any bigger then the height you have set. min-height will make sure there is a minimum of 40px but will still allow the box to expand.